# How do I Order on common attribute of two models in the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If i have two tables Books, CDs with corresponding models.

I want to display to the user a list of books and CDs. I also want to be able to sort this list on common attributes (release date, genre, price, etc.). I also have basic filtering on the common attributes.

The list will be large so I will be using pagination in manage the load.

```
items = []
items << CD.all(:limit => 20, :page => params[:page], :order => "genre ASC")
items << Book.all(:limit => 20, :page => params[:page], :order => "genre ASC")
re_sort(items,"genre ASC")
```

Right now I am doing two queries concatenating them and then sorting them. This is very inefficient. Also this breaks down when I use paging and filtering. If I am on page 2 of how do I know what page of each table individual table I am really on? There is no way to determine this information without getting all items from each table.

I have though that if I create a new Class called items that has a one to one relationship with either a Book or CD and do something like

```
Item.all(:limit => 20, :page => params[:page], :include => [:books, :cds], :order => "genre ASC")
```

However this gives back an ambiguous error. So can only be refined as

```
Item.all(:limit => 20, :page => params[:page], :include => [:books, :cds], :order => "books.genre ASC")
```

And does not interleave the books and CDs in a way that I want.

Any suggestions.

Comment: What are the common attributes of book and cd?

Comment: Genre, Price, location (in the store), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you can't change how books and CDs are stored in the database, but could you add an `items` view? Do you have any control over the database at all?

```
CREATE VIEW items
  (id, type, title, genre, created_at, updated_at)
  AS
  SELECT b.id, 'Book', b.title, b.genre, b.created_at, b.updated_at
    FROM books b
  UNION
  SELECT c.id, 'CD', c.title, c.genre, c.created_at, c.updated_at
    FROM cds c;
```

Comment: This is how we currently do it. I was hoping for a Rails solution, thaks though.

Comment: Well, the "Rails" thing to do is to create an `Item` model that maps to this table. Then you can either have `Book` and `CD` subclass `Item` (though getting Rails to figure out that inheritance won't be easy) or have it `belongs_to :base_item`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Item` model idea will work, but you are going to have to pull out all the common attributes and store them in `Item`. Then update all you forms to store those specific values in the new table. This way, adding a different media type later would be easier.

**Update after comment:**

What about a union? Do `find_by_sql` and hand-craft the SQL. It won't be simple, but your DB scheme isn't simple. So do something like this:

```
class Item < ActiveModel::Base
  attr_reader :title, :genre, :media_type, ...

  def self.search(options = {})
    # parse options for search criteria, sorting, page, etc.
    # will leave that for you :)
    sql = <<-SQL
    (SELECT id, title, genre, 'cd' AS media_type
     FROM cds
     WHERE ???
     ORDER BY ???
     LIMIT ???
    ) UNION
    (SELECT id, title, genre, 'book' AS media_type
     FROM books
     WHERE ???
     ORDER BY ???
     LIMIT ???
    )
    SQL
    items = find_by_sql(sql) 
  end
end
```

*untested*

Or something to that effect. Basically build the item rows on the fly (you will need a blank items table). The media_type column is so you know how to create the links when displaying the results.

Or...

Depending on how often the data changes you could, *gasp*, duplicate the needed data into the items table with a rake task on a schedule.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately I am accessing a DB that gets populated by a different application. So that won't work in this case.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I think that duplicating the data can be aliveated by having a view that does the union/join like James suggests. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

You can paginate on a results array, so leave pagination out of the invidual model queries, and add it to your results array:

re_sort(items,"genre ASC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => items_per_page)

Comment: Thanks simian, but if I paginate on the array I will pull in all records from the DB and have to sort them all. This is slow in Ruby, much faster in the DB. So I am hoping there is a DB solution. If not then yes I'll have to resort to your suggestion.

Comment: If you don't mind writing a more complex sql statement by hand, you can use paginate_by_sql()
http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb